# Is it possible to require checkout in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

Is it possible to configure Alfresco to always require that a file be checked out before it can be updated?

Answer (score 2):

Behaviours can do the trick. You definitely want to leverage  [ContentServicePolicies.OnContentPropertyUpdatePolicy](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/repo/content/ContentServicePolicies.OnContentPropertyUpdatePolicy.html). You might need [CheckOutCheckInServicePolicies.OnCheckIn](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/repo/coci/CheckOutCheckInServicePolicies.OnCheckIn.html) as well.